Push Down Automata for the language L = { a^i b^j c^k | i, j, k >= 0 and j = i + 2k }
I drew PDA diagram for this language but it still does not work. Can some please help me? My PDA accepts 'bc' which it should not. I have no idea to control the b and c of the language. My scala code for the pda is below.
PDA = PDA(
    states = Set(0, 1, 2, 3),
    symbols = Set('a', 'b', 'c'),
    alphabets = Set("A", "B"),
    trans = Map(
      (0, Some('a'), "Z") -> Set((0, List("A", "Z"))),
      (0, Some('a'), "A") -> Set((0, List("A", "A"))),
      (0, None, "Z") -> Set((3, List("Z"))),

      (0, Some('b'), "A") -> Set((1, List())),
      (0, Some('b'), "Z") -> Set((1, List("B", "Z"))),

      (1, Some('b'), "A") -> Set((1, List())),
      (1, Some('b'), "Z") -> Set((1, List("B", "Z"))),
      (1, Some('b'), "B") -> Set((1, List("B", "B"))),
      

      (1, None, "Z") -> Set((3, List("Z"))),

      (1, Some('c'), "B") -> Set((2, List())),

      (2, Some('c'), "B") -> Set((2, List())),

      (2, None, "Z") -> Set((3, List("Z"))),
    ).withDefaultValue(Set()),
    initState = 0,
    initAlphabet = "Z",
    finalStates = Set(3),
  )



What's your question? What's the issue?

My pda accepts 'bc' which it shouldn't. I have no idea what transition to add to control the acceptance of 'c' comming after 'b'

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You currently have a pda for the language L = {a^i b^j c^k | j = i + k}
To change it to the language you want, you have to change the transitions
(0, Some('b'), "Z") -> Set((1, List("B", "Z"))),

(1, Some('b'), "B") -> Set((1, List("B", "B"))),

to
(0, Some('b'), "Z") -> Set((1, List("B", "B", "Z"))),

(1, Some('b'), "B") -> Set((1, List("B", "B", "B"))),

